# Nobody can enter my network, with 1 exception

Tags: networking

I'm trying to setup an audio stream with Icecast and Ices, both are running fine and on my local network I can connect to the stream and listen to it. I'm doing this with 2 other people on different networks and they cannot connect, the following are the things I/we have tried:

```
port-forwarded in router settings, with IP/port of the laptop icecast is running on.
Disabling firewall on my laptop
Disabling firewall for my router 
Disabling both at the same time
```

Still no luck, in our desperation I tried to host a minecraft server (xd) which worked fine in the past, but that doesn't work either. When my friend scans the ports (25565 for minecraft, 8000, 6969 or 7999 for icecast, tried all three) they see that the port is "filtered". On my network another port is "open" for a program called xxter and they CAN connect to that, this brings them to a login screen for that service (its a program to control lights and stuff in the house).

Port forwarding image:

[image]

Comment: "filtered" means that the packet is not getting through. Could you add more info about your router and port-forwarding?

Comment: I have used normal port forwarding on the IP that the server uses, for both options UDP and TCP, and saved that. These were the settings that I used before and it worked back then. What kind of router details were you looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for the router model, and perhaps also a screenshot of its port-forwarding rules.

Comment: the router used is an 'Eurodocsis 3.0 modem', I've added a picture of the port forwarding in the post in a link (below 10 points can't imbed it)

Comment: What public IP does the router display?

Comment: @gronostaj: IP is kind of private and shouldn't be communicated.

Comment: Try to port-forward the range of 8000-8010.

Comment: @harrymc I'd argue that's not really the case in the era where everyone is behind a NAT and you can scan entire IPv4 address space in an hour. But okay, what are the first two octets of router's public IP address? Octets are the parts separated with dots, so for example if my IP was `151.101.1.69` the first two octets would be `151.101`